# Polymer consume HAL+JSON restful api

Tags: polymer, spring-hateoas

I have a Spring HATEOAS restful api to provide datas for my polymer front-end.

Data is received like this:

```
GET /api/tips/news : 

[ {
  "id" : 68,
  "content" : "example tip",
  "score" : 1,
  "creationDate" : 1456257119018,
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:81/api/tip/68"
  }, {
    "rel" : "author",
    "href" : "http://localhost:81/api/user/59"
  }, {
    "rel" : "for",
    "href" : "http://localhost:81/api/class/65"
  }, {
    "rel" : "against",
    "href" : "http://localhost:81/api/class/66"
  }, {
    "rel" : "comments",
    "href" : "http://localhost:81/api/tip/68/comments"
  } ]
} ]
```

Problem is that I want to get `author` property from links, so I want to do a second request once the first one is complete. To do this, I have a component that includes an `iron-ajax` component, to do the first api with my api Key and all the security stuff.

Here is how I do the first api call:

```
          <bnstips-api uri="/tip/news" result="{{data}}" auto></bnstips-api>
          <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
            <template>
                <tip-card tip=[[item]]></tip-card>
            </template>
          </iron-list>
```

and here is the `tip-card` component:

```
<dom-module id="tip-card">
    <style>
    </style>
    <template>
        <paper-card>
            <div class="card-content">
                [[tip.content]]

                Author:<bnstips-api api-path="[[tip.links.1.href]]" result={{author}} auto></bnstips-api> [[author.name]] [[tip.links.1.href]]
            </div>
            <div class="card-actions">
                <paper-button>Upvote !</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-card>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "tip-card",
        properties: {
            tip: {
                type: Object,
                value: {}
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

the api-path property is used to provide full path instead of just uri, here is the logic behind (in bnstips-api):

```
    if(this.uri != "" || this.uri != undefined){
        this.url = basePath+this.uri+"?apiKey="+apiKey;
    }
    if(this.apiPath != ""){
        this.url = this.apiPath+"?apiKey="+apiKey;
    }
```

But I get this:

[image: bug example]

So the link is provided, but the second ajax request gets a wrong uri, because in the console, I can see that I get a request to `http://localhost:81/undefined?apiKey.....` even if the property is here.

How to avoid that?

EDIT:
I tried to `console.log(this.apiPath)` inside my `handleRequest()` method, and it shows the good value, seems like it's an asynchronous problem (second ajax request is sent before the first one actually ends, so the second one has an undefined path since it has to come from the first one. How to wait for the first one to finish before sending the second one?

Comment: Where is the variable "basePath" defined? Inside a function or inside "properties object"?

Comment: unside a function, just before the two if statement you see. But problem is not that, it's apiPath being undefined while it should not be.

Comment: You make the comment that you think that the 2nd ajax request is sent before the first completes, but nowhere do you show how you are calling the ajax requests. I assume its somewhere inside bnstips-api, but we only see snippets of that. Does the `iron-ajax` element have an `auto` attribute, or what is your logic to call `generateRequest()`?

Comment: That's not `HAL` btw.